# How to make hr designer

Tags: html, css

Want to make hr like this **img1**

[image]
and

**img2**

[image]

don't known how to achieve this.

Comment: i think you can achieve this by setting border image in css    refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Comment: pseudo elements might also work nicely.

Comment: @arjun not so good with css could you please provide code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that using an `<hr>` is *not* the recommended way to do that.  You could just try:

```
<div><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llk2U.png'><div>
```

Or use a `css` class to make it a bit more elegant:

```css
.whybuyfromus
{
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llk2U.png') no-repeat;
  height: 101px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="whybuyfromus" />
```

Comment: please give full way to achieve it along with css i tried but had no luck

Comment: Great change to 'contain'. Much more usable.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this already has an accepted answer but I wanted to see if it was possible to make a fully responsive version with CSS. I found a solution using flexbox:

```css
.fancy-hr {
  display: flex;
  background-image:
    url(http://i.imgur.com/ZmheWg5.png),
    url(http://i.imgur.com/ph3e3OT.png);
  background-size: 115px 100%;
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 37px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 115px;
}

.fancy-hr:before,
.fancy-hr:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/NBus6Hr.png) repeat-x;
}

.fancy-hr span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 37px;
}

.fancy-hr span:before,
.fancy-hr span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fancy-hr span:before {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/wMU1oDn.png);
  float: left;
}

.fancy-hr span:after {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/4Q2el3J.png);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-hr"><span>Text here</span></div>
```

Comment: This is the better way. It allows the text to be changed directly from code.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```css
  .hr {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llk2U.png);
    height: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hr" />
```